# NestJS and Prisma, do we really need DTOs for validation when we could use Prisma Generated Type?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, prisma, dto, class-validator

I m building a NestJS project using Prisma ORM, and after some tutorial and check on the subject, I don't see (or seem to understand) the use of DTO here, when we could use the Prisma Generated Type

It's seems to be a duplication of what we already did in the Prisma Schema, and could lead to bad update later as we will have to update both the schema and the DTOs

After some search on it I come to the solution to directly use the Prisma Generated Type (as UserCreateInput / UserGetPayload)

here is the code that I did :

users.interface.ts

```js
import { type Prisma } from "@prisma-postgresql";

// select for query filtering
export const UsersSelect = {
    name: true,
    email: true,
} satisfies Prisma.UsersSelect;
// UsersGetPayload is autogenerated by prisma after migration
export type Users = Prisma.UsersGetPayload<{ select: typeof UsersSelect }>;
```

users.service.ts

```js
import { Injectable } from "@nestjs/common";

// prisma import
import { PrismaPostgresqlService } from "../../prisma/services/prisma-postgresql.service";
import { Users, UsersSelect } from "../interfaces/user.interface";

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
    private prismaSQL;

    constructor(prismaSQL: PrismaPostgresqlService) {
        this.prismaSQL = prismaSQL;
    }

    async findAll(): Promise<Users[]> {
        return await this.prismaSQL.users.findMany({
            select: UsersSelect,
        });
    }
}
```

with this I can have my own type coming directly from prisma

I don't know if it's indeed a good solution or not, maybe I m missing the point of DTOs here ?

Why would it be a good idea to still use DTOs in my case ? or is this a good solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resume for people coming by here, actually the only use case for DTOs with Prisma is for Swagger

You can't annotate Prisma Generated Type with the Swagger decorator, so if you want your documentation to be clear and complete, you will have to use DTOs until Prisma integrate this feature

Actually there is a way to make DTOs fast and without risk until this feature come out

1. use a Prisma DTOs generator tools : https://github.com/robblovell/prisma-generator-nestjs
2. use the Swagger CLI integrated in your nestjs project to handle the decorator : https://docs.nestjs.com/openapi/cli-plugin

I think it's the best way of handling this until Prisma add this feature

Answer (score 0):

Valentin, 
IMHO, DTOs are not always required. It depends on how you are organizing your app. If you are not interested in decoupling your code from the framework you are using, it sounds good to use the auto-generated types. As you said, it can bring more complexity than what you need. I would suggest starting that way, and as your app evolves it will show the necessity of creating DTOs or not.

Comment: That is the point of my question, I don't know why would I need it later, even if my app evolves, what are the need I could meet later ? 
As I said, everyone (even NestJS in their exemples) seems to be using DTOs at the start, so what I want to point is **Are we missing the power of prisma** ? Like is everyone using Dtos Cause they didn't find / look a way to directly use prisma to do it ?
That is what I m trying to understand here, as you said, maybe later I will see the use of DTOs, but I want to find what could be this reason

Comment: scenario 1: You have a REST API that provides a GET for the user resource. The contract (data representation) that you have defined for the route has more information than you would have in a specific domain model. In the backend, you are gathering info from multiple models (user, address, payment, etc.) and then returning it to the client. In that case, I see the need for a DTO.

Comment: scenario 2: You have a REST API that provides POST, PATCH, and GET routes for user resource. For the POST DTO, you defined the contract with some fields being mandatory, such as name, email, and password. For the PATCH DTO you are not allowing changes on field email, then you will not have this field, and the name and password are optional. And, the GET DTO has more info than the POST and PATCH DTOs, for instance, it would contain the fields: id, name, email, password, createdAt, updatedAt. So, your GET DTO can be reused by the POST and PATCH to return the result to the client.

Comment: I hope that clarifies a bit for you :)

Comment: thanks for the example :) 

Taking everything you said, PRISMA type do handle and allow almost all the case EXCEPT one, the PUT/PATCH case 

With the generated type you can't specifically say what is not allowed or not to be updated, so you have to manually extract which data should be updated and the request will not be rejected if it's pass data that should not be allowed to be updated

This do not affect documentation as we can specify allowed params with NestJS decorators 

And this should soon be covered by the Prisma team, as this is one of the most requested feature

Comment: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/3401

So when this will be added to prisma, there should be a new generated type for only allowed property to be updated, and all the case should be covered 

That aside, when this will be added to PRISMA, all the case where DTOs could be used would be gone right ?

Comment: For your case case, yes. Although, as I said, you are being tight coupling to the framework. As you are using its auto-generated types all over your app. And, there is nothing wrong with going that way, it is just a matter of trade-offs that we always have to make when building software.

Comment: Yes, in the end if we think about the day we might want to change the framework we use it might be the best to go with DTO, also they are some tool that exist to update our DTO using the prisma schema

Comment: In the end it might be best to use DTOs, allowing swagger to work properly and decoupling the solution from the framework